# Query a DataBase with Mongodb 3.x syntax?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to return all documents in my database with the query {isActive: true}. Here is my route:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const assert = require('assert');
const port = 4000;
const fs = require('fs');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/iRateIt";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/iRateIt");

app.use("/",(req,res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client){
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to server");

        const db = client.db("IRateIt");
        findDocuments(db, function() {
            client.close();
          });

    const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
        var query = {isActive: true};
        // Get the documents collection
        const collection = db.collection('professors');
        // Find some documents
        collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
          assert.equal(err, null);
          console.log("Found the following records");
          console.log(docs);
          callback(docs);
        });
      }
}
```

My log is as follows:

```
Server running on port 4000
Connected successfully to server
Found the following records
[]
```

Meaning it is not finding anything. There is probably something wrong with my syntax or something but I have been working on this for many days and cannot find the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: mongo shell log

```
> use IRateIt
switched to db IRateIt
> show collections
> db.collection.find()
> db.professors.find()
> db.professors.findOne()
null
>
```

edit #2 More log

```
> use iRateIt
switched to db iRateIt
> show collections
professors
responses
users
> db.professors.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afb358a21e490324913a75a"), "firstname" : "1", "lastname" : "2", "isActive" : true, "email" : "3", "password" : "4", "confirmpassword" : "4", "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5afb35a521e490324913a75b"), "firstname" : "2", "lastname" : "2", "isActive" : false, "email" : "3", "password" : "4", "confirmpassword" : "4", "__v" : 0 }
>
```

Comment: No results with `{}` for the query means that you are typically pointing at the wrong source. Either the database is actually different to the one you think you are selecting or the collection is different to what you think. Show how you access this data from the `mongo` shell. i.e How you connect, change database to the one you are trying to use here and select at least one document from the collection. Kind of confusing why you are connecting via mongoose AND MongoClient, but the first issue to sort out is where your data actually is. Chances are it's really in the "test" database.

Comment: Please don't take screenshots. Your code and data is "text", so instead you are expected to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50361232/edit) and include the "text". On your current reputation score there is actually a message telling you this when you attempt to upload an image into your post. Also please put any "details" in the question. Comments are merely for notifying those who asked you for clarification that you actually have "edited your question" and included the details asked for.

Comment: Did you do `use iRateIt` before you issued a query? This is exactly why you are being asked to put details "in your question". There's just so many things we cannot tell from a screenshot, and using a GUI also complicates matters. For all we know there could be a "space" leading or trailing on the name in error, but we cannot tell from a screenshot. Hence why "use the shell".

Comment: Thats `iRateIt`. Your GUI shows a "lowercase" `i`. Type in `show dbs` while you're at it.

Comment: Holy cow I realized the problem this whole time was using a lowercase i in the original code. What a dumb mistake. Thank you for helping me catch that!